# Многочисленные Черные речки

Tags: топонимика

Как мы все знаем, Пушкин стрелялся с Дантесом не Черной речке.
Но, на самом деле, этих Черных речек по всей России очень много. Например, есть Черная речка в Крыму, она впадает в море в Инкермане под Севастополем и образует заповедное урочище Чернореченский каньон.
А почему речки так настойчиво называют Черными? Если взять ту же крымскую речку, ничего черного (в плане цвета) в ней нет. Мне кажется, что название дается не за цвет, а за что-то еще.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

чёрный - Чёрная вода. Глубокое место.

чёрный - Чёрные воды, стоячие, болотные.

чёрный - Чёрная речка, обратная, т. е. не приток, а рукав, большей частью только в половодье, глухая речка.

черновина - яма, бакалдина.

черновина - окошко в болоте.

черень - вода; река; болото.

черень - болотистое место.

черни - мелкие прибрежные места в Каспийском море.

чернеина - чернеина ж. арх. ручейки, по белой, от ягеля, тундре.

черноводье - черноводный горный поток, черноводье ср. мутница, грязная вода половодья.

черноречье - черноречье ср. мелкие речки по болоту.

статья целиком здесь: http://andrej102.ru/estest/nat/natSH/natSH0206a.htm

Answer (score 1):

Да, речек с названием "Чёрная" в России много. На Чёрной речке стоит, между прочим, хутор Кружилин, родина гениального писателя Советской России и, как говорилось тогда, всего прогрессивного человечества Михаила Александровича Шолохова. На одной Чёрной речке гения убили, на другой - гений родился. Влияет ли название речки на судьбу человека? Нет, конечно. Но какая-то мистика с этим названием связана. Вы так не считаете? А если бы Пушкин стрелялся на речке с другим названием, может, исход был бы другим?

Comment: Я считаю! И тоже не верю в простые совпадения. Хотя наша, крымская, Черная речка, вроде, ни за чем плохим замечена не была.